# Wrapper localstorage and appSettings nativescript/angular at the same time

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Im migrating an angular webapp to use nativescript also.
My problem is that i have an AuthService class that is the owner of the security(Login, refreshToken, isLogged, etc...). The webApp is implemented to use localstorage, and in native i have to implement it with appSettings. So, my question is:

How can i make a class that support boths of them? I do not want to repeat all my code generating a tns.ts file for nativescript. Suggestions?

Comment: Use [nativescript-localstorage](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage) plugin. It creates methods similar to web local storage and saves data to a file. The new Pro version is paid, I believe the old version still works, it's a simple plugin.

Comment: @Manoj yes i saw it, but is paid and the old version has not support :(

Comment: As I already mentioned, it's a simple plug-in. You may even mock the functionality based on the given idea or opt for paid plugin if you want it to be easier.